# How to make changes in an Azure App Service, when you have lost all the local data of the project?

Tags: azure, azure-web-app-service

I've been working in a web page and I´ve already upload that page as an app service in azure, but my local machine has crashed and I have lost all my local data, and I don't know how to make new changes into my web page.

I already access to my azure account from visual studio, and I can see my source code, but the changes are no getting stored into the live web page.

Comment: What, exactly, are you trying to do? Did you use github (or other version control approach) to push your changes to web apps, or did you ftp? if the former, just re-clone your repo and keep going. If it was local git, or you ftp'd your content, then just ftp content back to local machine and keep going. Not really sure what else there is to do...

Comment: Thanks, I just re-clone my project via FTP.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

> I already access to my azure account from visual studio, and I can see my source code, but the changes are no getting stored into the live web page.

According to your description, if you just want to change and store the codes in the azure, I suggest you could access the source code by using Kudu tools.

You could open it by add "scm" in the websites url like below:

```
http://{yourwebappservicename}.scm.azurewebsites.net/
```

Then you could click the cmd button and you could find your project files like below:

[image]

[image]

Then you could locate your web sites files as below path.

```
site-->wwwrot-->youfiles
```

If you want to change its content you could click below button.

[image]

After changing the file's code, you could click the save button.

If you want to change the code and rebuild the application, you could only download the code to the local.

One way is using FTP to access the azure folder and copy it to local.

Another way is you could clone the whole web sites form the azure to your local visual studio by using VS team explorer.

Besides, I suggest you could use some online source code tool(Like [GitHub](https://www.infragistics.com/community/blogs/dhananjay_kumar/archive/2016/07/21/step-by-step-working-with-github-repository-and-visual-studio-2015.aspx) and [VSTS](https://www.visualstudio.com/en-us/docs/git/share-your-code-in-git-vs)) to help you manage your projects.

More details about how to use local git to clone the whole application to local, you could refer to below steps.

1.Fistly set your deployment username and password.
[image]

2.Enable local git:

[image]

[image]

3.Find the git url in the overview.

[image]

4.Open the teamview explorer in the VS.

[image]

5.Copy the gir url and click clone button.

[image]

6.Then it will show the windows to type the deployment username and password in step one.

[image]

7. Then you could double click the local git, you will find all files are clone to your local.